# port number of database produce error message

Tags: jdbc, oracle10g, database-connection, relational-database, resultset

I'm writing a simple java program (Jcreator as my IDE) to connect with Oracle Database (using SQL Plus / Oracle 10g). I first downloaded the jar file and copied it into bin directory in oracle directory. Then, I added the jar file to my JDK and wrote this code :

```
 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
 Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
 "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:amani","system","a123");    
 Statement stmt=con.createStatement();    
 ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");  
while(rs.next())  
System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+" - "+ rs.getString(2)+" -  "+rs.getInt(3)+"\n");
```

The problem is when  I use the default port number  1521, I do not get any results and no error messages appear.
and I know that I'm supposed to use my own database port number which is 1158, but then I get

```
   java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Bad packet type
```

What am I doing wrong, can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Java so - the following might be irrelevant nonsense so I apologize if that's the case.

Anyway, shortly: `1521 is most probably the port you should use (not 1158). Credentials you provided (username = system, password = a123) are wrong; use username = scott, password = tiger instead`

---

A longer version of the above statement: you should have access to the database; seeing your code, it is installed on your own computer. Is it up and running, i.e. can you connect to it via SQL*Plus?

Saying that you are

> supposed to use my own database port number which is 1158

well, I doubt that. If you installed everything *by default*, then your database port number is 1521, while 1158 is reserved for OEM (Oracle Enterprise Manager database console) so I don't think that 1158 is what you should use. See [Managing Oracle Database Port Numbers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/install.102/b15660/app_port.htm).

Furthermore, is your database name really "amani"? That's what this

```
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:amani","system","a123"
                                  -----
                                  this
```

suggests. In order to get its port, TNSPING it using command prompt (I've removed unnecessary part of the output): I can't tnsping *amani* (obviously, I don't have access to it)

```
c:\Temp>tnsping amani

TNS-03505: Failed to resolve name
```

but I can tnsping my own XE database:

```
c:\Temp>tnsping xe

Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = my-laptop)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))
OK (110 msec)
```

See? It is "OK", and its port is 1521. Do it on your computer in order to find that information.

Finally, **username and password**: you used one of *special*, most powerful users in your database, SYSTEM (another one is SYS). It doesn't contain the EMP table - it belongs to user SCOTT (whose default password is TIGER).

As you're on Oracle 10g, if I remember well, SCOTT is one of pre-installed schemas so you should be able to connect to it. Check it as following: on my XE, I'm connected as SYS:

```
SQL> select username, account_status from dba_users;

USERNAME                       ACCOUNT_STATUS
------------------------------ --------------------------------
SYS                            OPEN
SYSTEM                         OPEN
ANONYMOUS                      OPEN
SCOTT                          LOCKED
HR                             OPEN
<snip>

SQL> alter user scott account unlock;

User altered.

SQL> alter user scott identified by tiger;

User altered.

SQL> connect scott/tiger@xe
Connected.

SQL> select count(*) From emp;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        12

SQL>
```

I hope you understood what I did.

That much about Oracle part of the story; I really wouldn't know what to do if that doesn't help, in order to make your Java side work. Hopefully, someone else will be able to assist.

Comment: I first used the hr database but I changed it because I thought that was the problem. At instalition time of SQL Plus I changed the default passwords with a123 that's why i used it . And yes SQL Plus is on my  computer and i got the port number 1158 from the information I was given after the instalition process : 
 `The Database Control URL is http://DESKTOP-Q6L1LKP:1158/em
Enterprise Manager Database Control URL - (amani) :
http://DESKTOP-Q6L1LKP:1158/em
The iSQL*Plus URL is:http : //DESKTOP-Q6L1LKP:5560/isqlplus
The iSQL*Plus DBA URL is : http://DESKTOP-Q6L1LKP:5560/isqlplus/dba`

Comment: it most probably that I did something wrong with the connection information that you have pointed out. So, I really appreciate it and I hope it'll work